# why does jqxgrid not work in IE 11 but works in chrome

Tags: jqxgrid

I am using `JQxGrid` within my Angular 8 application and while everything works in IE 11, if I add the `jqxGridModule` with just import in `appModule.ts` it fails in IE with following error in `vendor.js`

```
var dataType = that.source._source.dataFields.find(gridField => gridField.name === dataField).type;
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: What does the error say? IE does not support arrow functions, `=>`. Try `function(gridField) { return gridField.name === dataField }`

Comment: ok this is a generated vendor.js, i do not have much control over that code. Can you give me an example may be iam not fully understanding your comment please